# Table is generated smaller then coded

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this table in Bootstrap 3 that should be responsive, but the table columns are still shrink-ed to fix on the screen.

The table should have a width of 1450px, but is shown in my screen as 1275px.

Even when using `<table class="table" width="1450px">` the table is shown smaller.
Also using `<div class="table-responsive" style="overflow-x:auto;">` is not changing the output.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
<h2 class="page-header">Maak calculatie</h2>

<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table">

    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th width="100px">Aantal</th>
        <th width="250px">Omschrijving 1</th>
        <th width="250px">Omschrijving 2</th>
        <th width="250px">Omschrijving 3</th>
        <th width="100px">Verkoop</th>
        <th width="500px">Opmerkingen</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control no-border input-sm" id="aantal" name="aantal" value=""></div></td>
        <td><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control no-border input-sm" id="omschr_1" name="omschr_1" value=""></div></td>
        <td><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control no-border input-sm" id="omschr_2" name="omschr_2" value=""></div></td>
        <td><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control no-border input-sm" id="omschr_3" name="omschr_3" value=""></div></td>
        <td><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control no-border input-sm" id="prijs" name="prijs" value=""></div></td>
        <td><div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control no-border input-sm" id="opm" name="opm" value=""></div></td>
      </tr>
    <tbody>

</table>                        
</div>                      
</div>                      
</div>
```

I am only getting a horizontal scroll bar when the make my browser very small.
[image]

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Native `table` elements will always render dimensions according to the content inside them. Using CSS's `table-layout: fixed;` you can apply a larger width (but afaik never larger than 100%).

Comment: you can set the table-layout to fixed, `.table-responsive table.table {table-layout:fixed;}` but you'll loose responsive if cell's width remains inline style or table-layout not reset via mediaquerie

Comment: can u share a working snippet or codepen or, any similar so that we can see the issue you are facing, and also `<th width: in pixels, is Not supported in HTML5`